# How to hide system notifications in Ventura?

Tags: macos, alert

How can I hide these alerts? They're constantly popping up.

[image]

I've set all the system notifications in my notifications centre to "off", like this, but they still appear:

[image]

Do I need to set one of the "application notifications" to off too? If so, which?

UPDATE: I'm still getting these "Approve" messages. I've turned off all application notifications, but is there a way to disable these short of turning off ALL notifications?

[image]

Comment: Try Turn off "Automatic Update"

Comment: When you say "constantly", are you getting other notifications, apart from the one telling you there's a new OS update that you ought to install? You can set Software Update to install silently.

Comment: Thanks @benwiggy - yes I'm also getting lots of notifications about connecting to other devices. I'll try to add a screenshot of those.